# How to generate parent_office_key in office dimension

Tags: ssis, ssas, data-warehouse, msbi

I am new to Data Warehouse development. Please help me in this issue.

I have an table Office with Office_id and Office_Parent_id. I am trying to create dimension from this table. I am struck at generating Foreign key of Office_Key which defines Office_Parent_key.

At the end there should be Office_key, Office_Parent_key, Office_name... etc.

In our Data Warehouse for every dimension we are generating Surrogate Key.

We are using SSIS ETL tool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use Foreign Keys for recursive parent-child relationships.   You create a parent-child dimension.

Google `ssas parent child dimension` for lots of documentation and examples.